# iOS custom image crop using paths

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgbitmapcontext

I need to implement a custom image crop on iOS and I can't seem to be able to find a technology that will allow me to do that easily.  The goal is to have an interface as follows:
[image: Custom image crop UI]

The idea is to have some sort of path or something around the face that the user can "nudge" around with their finger.  Is there a library for this?

I have played a bit with UIBezierPaths, but I don't see how they can be edited after being stroked.

The best that I can come up with is having the user manually draw a line around the face, but then the line wouldn't be editable.

Please help!  Does anyone know of a solution for this?  I am in a bind and need to provide my client with a solution.

Comment: So what you actually  want ? :-  Library to draw the path by the finger or to remove the portion after you draw with the finger path ??

Comment: I wanted a little of A and a little of B, however, this project is finished.

Comment: @mcottingham Could you please tell how you accomplished this functionality? I am in need of implementing something similar. would help a lot.